# How to pass this.state value in custom navigationOptions on React-Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm new to React-Native and I'm trying to figure out using React-Native Navigation how to pass values inside my custom header

Here's what my Component A looks like with the CustomHeader

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);       
    this.state = {
      sortId: 4
    }
 }

componentDidMount() {
    this.props.navigation.setParams({
      sortId: this.state.sortId
    })
}

static navigationOptions = {
    header: props =>    // Your custom header
      <CustomHeader
         sortId={props.navigation.params.sortId}
      />
};
```

In my CustomHeader Component, when I try to show the value like this

```
export default class CustomHeader extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }

 componentWillMount() {
   Alert.alert(this.props.sortId.toString());
 }
```

It's not working and I get the error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.sortId')`

But when I hardcode a value like below, it does work

```
static navigationOptions = {
    header: props =>    // Your custom header
      <CustomHeader
         sortId={4} //this works
      />
};
```

Any idea how I can pass parameters? What am I missing? I don't understand how to add parameters to `props` and access them in the navigationOptions.

Comment: Can you add the complete code, since it is hard to determine if the state which you want to pass is defined before the component is mounted or not?

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Do you get an error?

Comment: I have updated my question to answer both of your comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to access the `params` of the `navigationOptions`, then you need to change your code as

```
    static navigationOptions = {
    header: props =>    // Your custom header
      <CustomHeader
         sortId={props.navigation.state.params.sortId} //... state is missing
      />
};
```

as mentioned [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html)